# Is it the right flow for TCP hole punching for p2p application:

Tags: networking, tcp, network-protocols, hole-punching

1. Using stun I will get my external ip/port and NAT type.
2. On my middle server (public ip), I will register peers external ip/ports (Now server knows peer 1's and 2's external ip/port).
3. Exchange the ip/port (peer 1 will get to know the peer 2's ip/port).
4. Simultaneously make `connect()` call from both the peers.

Is it the right flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm is correct for UDP.  Take a look at these posts for more information:

- [TCP Hole Punch (NAT Traversal) Library or something?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443471/c-tcp-hole-punch-nat-traversal-library-or-something)
- [UDP Hole Punching](http://www.bford.info/pub/net/p2pnat/index.html#SECTION00030000000000000000)
- [TCP Hole Punching](http://www.bford.info/pub/net/p2pnat/index.html#SECTION00040000000000000000)

Comment: What extra I need to do for TCP??