# TCPclient in C# with public IP

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient, lan, tcplistener

Is it possible to use TCPclient and TCPlistener in c# with public IP addresses (or outside my LAN)? If NAT randomly assigns port number to each LAN communication, is there any way to know what port-number will be assigned to TCPlistener by its NAT-router to make TCPclient be able to communicate with it.
P.S. If it's not possible is there any other tool/technique to communicate outside the LAN without reconfiguring router (to forward all the messages to TCPlistener)?

Comment: The long and short answer is: NO!.

Comment: Nat traversal is possible. Not seen it done much with TCP. Some resources - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443471/tcp-hole-punch-nat-traversal-library-or-something    https://github.com/jasonpang/tcp-holepunching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at

```
TcpListener.AllowNatTraversal
```

This can be done with Toredo, 6to4, or an ISATAP tunnel.

Another option is UPnP if your NAT device supports it.